# Error converting data type varchar to datetime

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

i have 2 columns in DB Table `EntryDate` and it's type is `datetime`, and another one `EntryTime` is `Time`

and i have created a proc that takes datetime param `@DatetimeParam` it's like

```
select * from [TableName] where EntryDate+EntryTime <=@DatetimeParam
```

it doesn't work *Error converting data type varchar to datetime*.

i am working with sql2008 and c#

Comment: Why don't you store the Time in `EntryDate` as well, since its of type `DateTime`

Comment: How are you calling the stored procedure? The problem won't be with the stored procedure itself, it's how you're calling it.

Comment: datetime+time should be ok, whats a value of @DatetimeParam  ?

Answer (score 1):

for starters your table structure is redundant. Your `DateTime` column is capable of storing both the date & time components but even so. You must have an error in your C# code which isn't posted because if @DateTimePAram were a valid value, then your sql would work.

```
use TempDB

CREATE TABLE #temp (a DateTime, b Time)
INSERT INTO #temp (a,b) values ('2012-01-01', '12:00:00.000')
SELECT * FROM #temp where a+b < getdate()
DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: i know there is a reduntant due to business needs and application design it is a must to have EntryDate and EntryTime columns

Comment: ok. then post your c# code that calls this stored proc. I'm guessing you're passing your input in an invalid format.